# How to call setState from UserIdentity component in a Model in Yii

Tags: php, yii

When a user logs in to my Yii application, I set below properties in `authenticate` function of `UserIdentity` class:

```
$this->setState('nickname', $this->nickname);
$this->setState('thumb', $this->thumb);
```

I display **nickname** on the title bar in my view:

```
Yii::app->user->nickname
```

Now I have a feature where user can edit **nickname**. So when user edits it, I want to set it on the title bar too. For that I would have to call setState in a Model or in a Controller.

How do I set nickname from `Yii::app()->user` in a Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it again:

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('nickname','NEW VALUE');
```

And get it to use:

```
$nickname=Yii::app()->user->getState('nickname');
$model->nickname=$nickname;
$model->save();
```

Comment: @Hussain Sorry :) fixed